# Why does php artisan serve keep trying to rename my .env file?

Tags: php, laravel, git, phpstorm

I am having the toughest time with one of my laravel apps on my computer.  I run php artisan serve and it renames my .env file to '.env 4' or '.env 5' (which then results in error 500, because there is now no .env file.

It also deletes files that were and should be on my computer.  When I run git status, it shows the files as untracked changes (deleted files resources/views/success.blade.php, etc) and an added file of '.env 4'

If I manually rename the file, it looks ok until I run php artisan serve.  If I git restore the views that keep being deleted, they are restored but the same thing happens again when I run php artisan serve.

I'm ready to throw the computer out the window!!!  What the heck is going on?  I'm using PhpStorm if that helps.

Comment: I don't use php, but: are you sure it's php doing this? This is exactly the kind of file name that sharing servers (like Dropbox) use when they're trying to reconcile two different changes to a shared folder.

Comment: `php artisan serve` should not be doing any of that... I have never seen `serve` do any kind of modification to tracked files/files in the same directory/etc. I'd try creating a fresh instance of Laravel in a new folder, then try running `php artisan serve` there. Also, PhpStorm shouldn't have any bearing on this, unless PhpStorm has a built-in terminal that you're running this command through; but even then...

Comment: @torek THANK YOU!!!  The folder IS on my iCloud Drive.  I ended up deleting the folder and re-cloning it from GitHub, and the problem has not returned.